# Configure virtual host in Binami on OS X El Capitan is not work

Tags: nginx, bitnami

I'm install ing Bitnami on OS X EI with this application packages nginx,php,mysql and try to configure virtual host as the official website document but it is really not work as expected

This is my configuration

Step 1: Copy Demo to Apps directory

Step 2: Copy certs from PHPMYADMIN to /conf/certs.

Step 3: Add this line to /nginx/conf/bitnami/...>include "/Applications/nginxstack-1.10.3-0/apps/demo/conf/nginx-vhosts.conf";. Document said uncommend but the file is empty :smile:

Step 4: Add this line to include /nginx/conf/bitnami/...> "/Applications/nginxstack-1.10.3-0/apps/demo/conf/nginx-prefix.conf";

Step 5: restart all services and every is absolutely not work document said.

Why?

Comment: Bitnami Developer here. I was unable to reproduce the issue. I tried accessing via `localhost:8080/prefix` and `demo.example.com:8080` (I modified `/etc/hosts` to recognize `demo.example.com`) and everything worked successfully. How did you try to accesss? Which errors appear?

Comment: I've testing  as your too but i still not work for me

Comment: Which errors appear?

Comment: I got this 
2017/03/01 20:25:13 [error] 16996#0: *1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /vgo/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"

Comment: Why I can access only http://localhost:8080/demo/  but can not http://demo.example.com:8080 or http://demo.example.com

Comment: Now it is work if i access this  localhost:8080/demo url but can not demo.example.com

Comment: Did you modify your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: yes I have add more on this configuration I have more experience with another service they are work fine but when i try with bitnami it is easier to manage and configure but I don't why it is not work

Comment: Can you see these errors when accessing via `localhost:8080/demo` or the error only appears when trying to access `demo.example.com:8080`?